# What counts as "non-Stack Overflow"?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

For the [Polymath](//winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/polymath) and [Running Ragged](//winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/running-ragged) hats, does Meta Stack Overflow count? What about the alternate language SO's?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Only the English Stack Overflow is counted: those hats counterbalance the English-SO-only hats (for documentation and developer story).

Source: I implemented the hats.

Comment: Congrats on that Snapchat hat btw :)

Comment: @StephenLeppik Snap*h*at - you've got one too many letters. An easy mistake to make.

Comment: "Source: I implemented the hats." CITATION NEEDED! blah blah blah, overeliance on primary source blah blah... oh wait. Roughly as canonical as it gets Never mind. ;p

Comment: *Flag for original research*

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

It says Stack Overflow. There is only one Stack Overflow and its http://www.stackoverflow.com.

> Running Ragged
>
> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack **Overflow**) within 15 days.

Notice there is no s.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is kinda sorta part of Stack Overflow, though. This needs clarification from the team, really.

Comment: @ArtOfCode but you can't earn any rep on Meta SO, or to be exact, the rep on Meta SO is rep you earned on SO.